# How can I keep the property used for setting the JsonSubTypes?

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, deserialization

When deserializing my yaml-config with the Jackson Datamapper the value in the config that is used for deciding what subtype to create, is then ommited and not saved in the created java object.

This is the config I'm trying to read in...

```
#config
--- 
lists:
  - filename: filename.xlsx
    template: filename_template.xlsx
    type: classType #this value is ommitted
    ...
```

With this abstract class

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Example.class, name = "Example"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OtherExample.class, name = "OtherExample")
})
public abstract class Report {

    private String filename;
    private String template;
    private String type; //this value is always null

    public Report() {

    }
```

And creating and calling the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
mapper.enableDefaultTyping();
```

The String type should be either one of the values that JsonSubType option uses to set the type, instead of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JsonTypeInfo` is handled internally by `Jackson`. Property `type` is used to create specific class and you do not need it after deserialisation because you have an instance of that class. If `Jackson` instantiated `Example` object you know `type` was set to `Example` in `Yaml` file. If `Jackson` instantiated `OtherExample` object you know `type` was set to `OtherExample` in `Yaml` file, etc...

So, you can remove `private String type;` from `Report` class and use `getClass().getSimpleName()` for getting `type`.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I solved it by setting the value type in the constructors of the child classes.

```
public OtherReport() {
        super();
        super.setReportType("OtherReport");
    }
```